# The value of 'fieldsets[4][1]' must be a dictionary

Tags: python, django, tuples

I am using `AbstractUser` to create my custom account model in Django. Now I have a class in `admins.py` like so:

```
class CustomAccountAdmin(UserAdmin):
    model = CustomAccount
    add_form = CustomAccountCreationForm

    fieldsets = (
        *UserAdmin.fieldsets,
                                ('Access', {'fields': ('status', 'team', 'role')}
                                ), 
                                ('Other', {'fields': ('phone', 'address', 'description')}
                                )
        )
    )

admin.site.register(CustomAccount, CustomAccountAdmin)
```

I want to add more fields to my custom account admin and I get this error:

```
django.core.management.base.SystemCheckError: SystemCheckError: System check identified some issues:

ERRORS:
<class 'account.admin.CustomAccountAdmin'>: (admin.E010) The value of 'fieldsets[4][1]' must be a dictionary.

System check identified 1 issue (0 silenced).
```

This format is working properly but I want to add more:

```
fieldsets = (
    *UserAdmin.fieldsets,(
    ('Access', {'fields': ('status', 'team', 'role')})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are missing a trailing comma and you have an extra bracket. Try modifying as shown

```
 class CustomAccountAdmin(UserAdmin):
    model = CustomAccount
    add_form = CustomAccountCreationForm

    fieldsets = (
        *UserAdmin.fieldsets,
                                ('Access', {'fields': ('status', 'team', 'role')}
                                ), 
                                ('Other', {'fields': ('phone', 'address', 'description')}
                                ),
        )
```